# Regex match only URL's that dont contain special characters

Tags: regex

I have a list of URL's like so.

```
https://www.website.com/foo
https://www.website.com/foo/bar
https://www.website.com/foo?query=
```

And I want to have some Regex that only matches with `https://www.website.com/foo`

I have been trying something like `(?=.{23}).+(?!\?)` because I know the first part of the url will always be the same so I just want to not match if there are more than one / in the trailing path or if it has special characters like ? or =. I guess I'm not understanding why the negative lookahead isn't actually filtering out matches with those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
^https://[^/]+/[^/?]+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kczYD9/1)